# SSH Timeout issue

Tags: networking, ssh, gitlab

I am running SSH with Gitlab on digital ocean. Everything works fine for me, except one small issue.

everyday around 12 Noon, or 4/8 PM I cannot commit my code to Gitlab, as I use ssh key to submit my code and SSH gives me connection timeout. This give connection timeout for some 5-10 minutes and then it works. I notice those time are when it mostly refuse, but not necessarily refuse connection. 90% of case it works fine.

I search there is no specific cron is going that stop it, I ask Hosting (Digital Ocean) they says all seems right from their end, I try different ISP [3-4 ] to see if problem is with my ISP or machine, it is not. So it seems some software configuration issue on my server, but I am not sure why and how I debug and fix it. I have no clue how to handle it. Any expert opinion will help. Thanks.

it is ubuntu 18.04 LTS (We upgrade it from 16.04 LTS) and it has same issue when it was 16.04

EDIT:

We did the trace route then it connects and when it doesn't Trace route produce exact same result and it reach server well. As I say before, when SSH fail it still allow us to surf website hosted on that server and perform any other operation, just only SSH is giving timeout.

Edit 2:

I accidently forgot to close my ping to server, when it was connecting, and when I make the above edit I see that ping doesn't miss single time. it has 100% reach rate when it connects or not connect. So it is some SSH configuration only.

Comment: You haven't mentioned any OS/release details so we don't know what OSes or software stacks are involved, so why ask here?

Comment: @guiverc It is Ubuntu 18.04 as of now.

Comment: When these problems occur can you connect via terminal and ssh -vvv? This could maybe bring some info into this. The most verbose settings could maybe show what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: Is this a VM? Are you using a copied version? If so, take a look here 
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-regenerate-openssh-host-keys/

Comment: @It is VM, Digital ocean sell VPS (which are VM).. Not sure copied version comment. I download free edition of gitlab and has ubuntu, which get installed by hosting, but all other software are done by me.